# Create custom post type with parameters

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a lot of custom post types and i want to create them all with in the same function, so is there any way to send parameters to the function when i'm creating the custom post type.

I thinking of something like this:

```
function custom_poster($pluralName, $singularName) {
   // Create custom post type
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_poster' );
```

or:

```
function create($pluralName, $singularName)
{
  function custom_poster() {
     // Create custom post type and use $pluralName, $singularName)
  }

  add_action( 'init', 'custom_poster' );
}

create("myposts","mypost");
```

Comment: If you are familier with classes the here is a repository that i have created to make more custom post types. I know its lack of documentation. but maybe this will help you. https://github.com/jogeshpi03/WordPress-Custom-Post-Type

Comment: your are always welcome, i will improve it more later.